# Arraylist tomar el ultimo objeto. y reemplazar un append(";") por un(" ") en el ultimo objeto, Java

Tags: java

Hola buenas tardes necesitaría una ayuda con el siguiente método donde tengo una lista por ejemplo de habitaciones, y es imprimir una URL con los datos. solo que al ultimo dato de la lista necesitaría quitarle el .append(";") y reemplazarlo por (" ") solo en los casos del ultimo objeto (habitacion),

investigue pero no sabria que es lo mejor si el size o el lastIndexOf

solo necesitaria encontrar el ultimo room y quitarle el ; solo al ultimo. si me falto algo mas de informacion diganme. muchas gracias

````
```
   private String getFormattedRooms(List<HotelRoom> rooms) {
        StringBuilder formattedRooms = new StringBuilder();
        for (HotelRoom room : rooms) {
            rooms.get(rooms.size()-1); -->opcion 1
            rooms.lastIndexOf(room); --> opcion 2
            formattedRooms.append("1").append(getSupplierRoomType(room)).append(getChildrenAges(room)).append(";");
        }
        return formattedRooms.toString();
    }
````

Comment: Puedes hacer `return formattedRooms.substring(0, formattedRooms.length() - 1)`.

Comment: gracias no la había pensado a través del return, llego a mi casa y hago la modificación y pruebo.